# NestJS headers for static files

Tags: http-headers, nestjs

We add security headers to NestJS requests.

We also serve static html files.

```js
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TransformHeadersInterceptor());

app.useStaticAssets(join(__dirname, "..", "public"), {
    //index: false,
    redirect: false
});
```

The headers are added to NestJS controller output but not to html files from public.

How would we do this? Do we need to go to Express level?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I couldn't find any answers or solution after hours.

Comment: No, haven't found one :-(

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the headers to the static folder, this is the [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)

one example could be this in the **main.ts**

```
 app.useStaticAssets(`${__dirname}/public`,
  { setHeaders: (res, path, stat) => {
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  }});
```

you can add you headers in the setHeaders function 
Hope this help someone

Comment: That works perfectly, but it's weird because if you've enabled cors globally, u shouldn't do this configuration again, only for static assets...